# Remove second occurrence of given item from list - Racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, r5rs

I need to write a function called remove-2nd, which removes the second top-level occurrence of a given item from a list of items. This is what I have right now:

```
(define (remove-2nd item list)
(cond
  ((null? list) '())
  ((equal? item (car list))
   (cdr list))
  (else
   (cons (car list) (remove-2nd item (cdr list))) 
  )))
```

Right now, it only removes the first occurrence. 
(remove-2nd 'c '(a b c d c x c)) returns (a b d c x c) when I should get (a b c d x c).

Comment: Rename this function to `remove-1st`, then use it to implement `remove-2nd`.

Answer (score 1):

For empty and single-element lists, we just return the list. Otherwise, we see if the first item in the list is the same as the item we're trying to remove. If it is the item we're trying to remove, then we remove the next occurrence of that element in the rest of the list, if not, we recur on the rest of the list.

```
(define (remove-2nd item l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) '())
    ((null? (cdr l)) l)
    (else (if (equal? item (car l))
              (cons (car l) (remove item (cdr l)))
              (cons (car l) (remove-2nd item (cdr l)))))))
```

Using pattern matching in Racket:

```
(define (remove-2nd e l)
  (match l
    [(or `() `(e)) l]
    [(cons f r) (cons f (if (equal? e f) (remove e r) (remove-2nd e r)))]))
```

Some tests:

```
(remove-2nd 1 '())
; => '()
(remove-2nd 1 '(1))
; => '(1)
(remove-2nd 1 '(2))
; => '(2)
(remove-2nd 1 '(2 2))
; => '(2 2)
(remove-2nd 1 '(1 1))
; => '(1)
(remove-2nd 1 '(1 2))
; => '(1 2)
(remove-2nd 'c '(a b c d c x c))
; => '(a b c d x c)
```

Comment: Okay, this helped me understand better. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

General (tail call recursive) solution `remove-nth` and then special case `n = 2`.

```
(define (remove-nth item l n (test equal?) (acc '()) (counter 1))
  (cond
    ((null? l) (reverse acc))
    ((test (car l) item) (if (= counter n)
                             (remove-nth item (cdr l) n test acc (+ counter 1))
                             (remove-nth item (cdr l) n test (cons (car l) acc) (+ counter 1))))
    (else (remove-nth item (cdr l) n test (cons (car l) acc) counter))))

(define (remove-2nd item l (test equal?))
  (remove-nth item l 2 test))
```